# Can `needs:ref` take a tag in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Given 2 projects: ProjA and ProjB

ProjA has a job `JobA`:

```yaml
jobA:
  script:
    - echo "This is a meme, laugh." > meme.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - file.txt
```

ProjB has a job `JobB`:

```yaml
jobB:
  needs:
    - project: ProjA
      ref: nightly
      job: jobA
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - cat meme.txt
```

`nightly` is a tag on ProjA.

On GitLab 14.6, `JobB` gives the following error:

[image: This job depends on other jobs with expired/erased artifacts:]

Why does this fail so badly and how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

> Can `needs:ref` take a tag in GitLab?

This is `true` since for Gitlab the `tag` is basically a branch.

For the encountered error, maybe this will help:

According to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsproject

*When using `needs:project` to download artifacts from another pipeline, the job does not wait for the needed job to complete. `Directed acyclic graph` behavior is limited to jobs in the same pipeline.*

*Make sure that the needed job in the other pipeline completes before the job that needs it tries to download the artifacts.*

Comment: Yeah, the "nightly" job finished ages ago.

Comment: I might sound rude. But for sanity's sake. Does the last successful execution of the nightly jobA has artifacts?

Comment: Not at all, that's the first thing I checked haha.